# Join Tables and do Count by SQL

Tags: mysql

I have an idea to join tables and do count (do not want to use Group By), but still cannot produce the expected outcome, is there any simple way to do?

MainTable:

```
  ProductID  Cust    BuyTime
    100        A       10:01
    100        A       10:30
    200        C       15:05
```

Need to Get more info from this table:

```
ProductID  CustName    ViewComment     BuyTime
100        A            Yes           10:01
100        A            Yes           10:30
200        B            Yes           NULL
200        C            NULL          15:05
```

Expected Outcome:

```
ProductID  CustName  Nb_of_View  Nb_of_Buy     BuyTime
100        A          1           1            10:01
100        A          1           1            10:30
200        B          1           0            NULL
200        C          0           1            15:05
```

Comment: Which queries you've tried already? What's not good with the results they return?

Comment: I don't think you can do this through just joining the tables.  The secondary table needs to be a subquery or grouped somewhat intelligently.  All the answers I can think of use a Group By, why are you trying to avoid it?

Comment: Can you show me a sample SQL for question..? Thanks!!